# How is "CURSES" a pun for "cursor optimization"?

Tags: unix, command-line

I've begun implementing a support library for `curses` in Python.

Along the way, I became curious why the project was called "curses" to begin with. According to [one NCURSES documentation](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/intro.html), the name is explained thusly

> Curses is a pun on the name "cursor optimization"

I don't get it. How is "CURSES" a pun for "cursor optimization"?

*Note: I'm not sure what stack exchange this question belongs in. Trying here and open to suggestions on where to move the question.*

Comment: Not certain, might just refer to the amount of cursing involved before the library and working with terminfo/termcap/escape sequences

Comment: I think you're looking too much into it.  Cursor Optimization... Cursor... Curs... Curses.

Comment: @Quezocotl Right. That seems like what Jerry Coffin is saying.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting my question instead of suggesting a different stack exchange guys! Maybe I can get my Programmers score down into the negatives.

Comment: The cost of knowledge I guess. I have to pay reputation to get an answer for a question people don't want me to ask. At least I got my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of what curses does is optimize cursor control sequences so (for example) to backspace all the way to the beginning of a line, instead of writing out a bunch of back-space characters, it can issue one command to move the cursor to the beginning of the line, and one more to erase to the end of the line. At least at one time, it had a fair amount of logic to figure out the shortest sequence of characters it could write to accomplish a particular command (though many recent ones probably don't bother--it's no longer nearly as important as it was in the days of a terminal connected at 300 or 1200 bit per second).

The name is "optimizing" the (relatively long) sequence of characters "cursor optimization" down to the much shorter sequence of characters "curses".

Answer (score -2):

Wikipedia clarifies that "cursor" was derived from the slide rule's "runner" that lines up the parallel points on its sliding rulers that lets one note a parallel number on a rule when setting up a calculation and then for reading the results.  It enhances precision, especially where ruler's numbers are not next to each other; but on another row farther away on the interacting rulers.  Latin for "runner" is "cursor".  In Latin "curses" has no translation notable I can find.  (Though "prayer"/"supplication" is considered a possible English synonym; though it appears to tend to imply a request for restricting a relationship to something or someone. [Source: https://www.wordhippo.com/  And interact with page.]
  An implied English translation to Latin's "cursor" may be "courser".  Replacing the last two characters with "es" [which may also imply "escaped"/"enhanced" "sequence" (of characters or key stokes"], then gives in English "courses" which is also "paths to run" [herein being done virtually by the computer when using a shorter command].  That then being compressed back to its shorter Latin source gives "curses".  Memory space was costly on early computers.